# Similar Chrome extensions like Firefox F1

Tags: firefox-extensions, google-chrome-extensions

I have used [Mozilla Firefox F1](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/f1-by-mozilla-labs/) add-on.  I want exact functionality like this add-on provides -- yeah I know, Shareaholic, add this extension in Chrome, but every one of them opens a new tab.  Are there any such extensions?

Answer (score 0):

I've been using chrome for a while now and was desperate to have a similar to mozilla f1 button for it. I switched to Firefox as my main browser for the mean time until I get a proper similar extension for Chrome. Chrome is better and faster but sadly although it has a web store, it lacks many great addons and extensions. I advice you to switch to firefox 4. =) I am also desperate to have a proper download manager for Chrome such as downthemall. Too bad it has nothing so far.

Comment: I think your response should be in comment, not in answer. Anything not answering the question should be in comment.